# Acess 2013 - Query for number of payments for month in current year

Tags: ms-access-2013

I'm trying to make a query in Access 2013 that shows me how many payments I've received for month in the current year.  I tried using this:

Expr1: Count([Payment_ID])

However, it shows me all of the payments received without taking into account the current year nor without diving it per month.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built a table in Access and created this query....

[image]

This should produce what you want

Here is the data from the table:
[image]

And here is the results

[image]

Comment: Cool.  Though, I have it set up in the "Payment" table so it only shows "Date_of_Payment" where it uses the Data/Time data.  How would I set that up or do I have to divide up like you did?

Comment: Let me work that for you, I know how to do it in sql, just have to translate to Access